# My renewed passport dated from when I renewed it and not from the old expiry date, a difference of 6 months. Only valid for 4.5 years, not 5 years

Tags: passport-renewals

My renewed passport was dated from renewal date and not from expiry date of old passport. 6 months difference. Why?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the passport is valid for full 5 years, but the first 6 months of its validity overlap with the validity of the old passport. Yes, that's how it works. Moreover, not sure about other countries, but at least in my country, a passport's validity starts on the day of requesting it, not on the day you actually get it. That could be 30 days difference...

Comment: If that weren't the case, I'd simply renew my passport a few times right after I get it. Repeat 10 times and you're good for 50 years :-)

Comment: @Johnnyjanko many countries (most?) will normally cancel the old passport when issuing the new, so there won't be any overlap.

Comment: Which country issued the passport? Practices differ eg Cuba issues passports for six years that have to be extended for two years every two years.

Comment: @phoog Interesting. That doesn't happen in my country, AFAIK. But it has no effect on the original point (that is, this passport being valid for 5 years, not 4.5 years).

Answer (score 4):

This is the right behavior. The passport validity is usually fixed number of years starting from the day of renewal. Depends on country,age and passport type, passport validity can differ.

For instance, my passport is expiring on 1/08/2023. I choose to renew it on 1/03/2023. Then my expiry will be 1/03/2033, not 1/08/2033. (Dates in DD/MM/YYYY).

Answer (score 3):

The other answer explains the most common procedure but there have been exceptions.

Until 2018, the UK allowed you to renew early and get a passport valid for 10 years from the expiry date of the previous passport rather than the issue date of the new one.  There was a limit to how early you could renew but up to 10 years and 9 months was possible.

This caused problems for travel to the EU after Brexit as the EU only accepts passports issued less than 10 years ago.  This caused a lot of confusion.  The rule was not introduced because of Brexit, it already existed, but it did not apply to the UK while it was in the EU.

The practice ended in 2018 but passports of this type are still in circulation.

More details here: https://www.independent.co.uk/travel/europe/renew-passport-eu-expiration-rules-travel-b2274569.html

A similar rule applies to the annual vehicle safety test called the MOT.  You may get your vehicle tested up to one month before the expiry of the current certificate and the new certificate will expire a year after the expiry of the previous one.  This is still in effect and is better known.

Comment: @phoog Thanks for spotting and correcting that silly mistake.  For the moment, the UK is still in the UK.

Answer (score 1):

The point of expiring passports is to limit the period within which an invalid passport appears to be valid, and to keep your photo from getting too out-of-date. It’s not so that the government can collect a regular “passport rent”.  So the expiration date is based on when the passport was issued, not on how long you’ve been using passports.